# Async/Await, returned variable is undefined after XHR request

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am attempting to get a public IP address from an API and then having that IP to be used inside another function (`ninjaUniqueVisitorRequest()`).

I have the following code:

```
function ninjaGetIp() {
    var ipRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ipRequest.open('GET', "https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp=", true);
    ipRequest.send();
    ipRequest.onload = function () {
        if (ipRequest.status >= 200 && ipRequest.status < 400) { // If response is all good...
            return ipRequest.responseText;
        } else {
            console.log('There was an error retrieving the public IP.');
            return '127.0.0.1'; 
        }
    }
}

async function ninjaUniqueVisitorRequest() {
    // var ninjaSiteUuid = ninjaGetSiteUuid();
    // var ninjaFingerprint = await ninjaGetFingerprint();
    var ninjaPublicIp = await ninjaGetIp();
    console.log(ninjaPublicIp);
}
```

Currently, when I run `ninjaUniqueVisitorRequest();` the `console.log(ninjaPublicIp);` returns `undefined`.

I kind of understand that it returns straight away before the request has been made however thats what I thought I was fixing by using `async/await`.

Any ideas are appreciated!
PHP guy over here, go easy on me.

Comment: Your `ninjaGetIp()` function is not `async` and does not return a Promise.

Comment: I thought you simply put `async` on the function you're calling from. Also from my understanding `return xyz` will be converted to a promise anyway? I'm compiling with Babel.

Comment: If you want promised based AJAX use the fetch() API.

Comment: @KriiV it would be converted to a promise if you had _any_ `return` there and if you marked it with `async`. `ninjaGetIp` returns nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `ninjaGetIp function` is not a `Promise`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently your `ninjaGetIp` is not an awaitable `Promise`.

You can try just returning a new `Promise` that wraps the implementation or just add `async` keyword before the function.

```
function ninjaGetIp() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var ipRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ipRequest.open('GET', "https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp=", true);
        ipRequest.send();
        ipRequest.onload = function () {
            if (ipRequest.status >= 200 && ipRequest.status < 400) { // If response is all good...
                return resolve(ipRequest.responseText);
            } else {
                console.log('There was an error retrieving the public IP.');
                return resolve('127.0.0.1'); 
            }
        }
    });
    
}
```

Async sample

```
async function ninjaGetIp() {
            var ipRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ipRequest.open('GET', "https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp=", true);
            ipRequest.send();
            ipRequest.onload = function () {
                if (ipRequest.status >= 200 && ipRequest.status < 400) { // If response is all good...
                    return ipRequest.responseText;
                } else {
                    console.log('There was an error retrieving the public IP.');
                    return '127.0.0.1'; 
                }
            }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `ninjaGetIp` is not awaitable. You have to return a `Promise` in order to be able to `await`.

```
   async function ninjaGetIp() {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            var ipRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ipRequest.open('GET', "https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp=", true);
            ipRequest.send();
            ipRequest.onload = () => {
                if (ipRequest.status >= 200 && ipRequest.status < 400) { // If response is all good...
                    resolve(ipRequest.responseText);
                } else {
                    console.log('There was an error retrieving the public IP.');
                    reject('127.0.0.1');
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Also, you can simplify it and use `fetch` which returns a promise instead of using all the code required to build up an `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
async function ninjaGetIp() {
    return fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp=');
}
```

**TL;DR;**

If you want to stick with `XMLHttpRequest`, I would create a wrapper for it because it's a lot of redundant code: Here's an example:

```
class HttpClient {
    constructor(){}
    async get(url) {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = (evt) => {
                if (evt.currentTarget.readyState === 4 && evt.currentTarget.status === 200) {
                    try {
                        const response = JSON.parse(evt.currentTarget.response);
                        resolve(response);
                    } catch (exception) {
                        reject(exception);
                    }
                }
            };
            xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
            xhttp.send();
        });
    }
    async post(url, data) {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = (evt) => {
                if (evt.currentTarget.readyState === 4 && evt.currentTarget.status === 200) {
                    try {
                        const response = JSON.parse(evt.currentTarget.response);
                        resolve(response);
                    } catch (exception) {
                        reject(exception);
                    }
                }
            };
            xhttp.open('POST', url, true);
            xhttp.send(data);
        });
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
const httpClient = new HttpClient();
const data = await httpClient.get('some url');
```

1. [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
2. [Async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
3. [Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: I'm using XHR for compatibility purposes... Not sure if that's correct though.

Comment: `XHR` still has functionality not present in `fetch` - so, it is perfectly cromulent to use XHR - however, the code in the question does not use any of this functionality

Comment: Your `HttpClient` leaves the promise unsettled if the response has an error code. You're also repeating a lot of code that could easily be shared between `get()` and `post()` methods.

Comment: Agreed. There is alot of work to do in this to make it production ready. This was a quick example of how to throw his existing code and wrap it in a class. Not to mention it is lacking the rest of the HTTP verbs (PATCH, DELETE, PUT, etc...)